# looping motion effect implementing react-spring useTrial with react-konva

Tags: react-spring, react-konva

Good Morning, I have some issues implementing react-spring with react-konva.
I have three sets of Rects animated with useTrial to create a looping motion effect.

```
import { useTrail, animated } from "@react-spring/konva";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Layer, Rect, Stage, Text } from "react-konva";

const dummy_items = [
  "item1",
  "item2",
  "item3",
  "item4",
  "item5",
  "item6",
  "item7",
  "item8",
  "item9",
  "item10",
  "item11",
  "item12",
  "item13",
  "item14",
  "item15",
  "item16",
  "item17",
  "item18",
  "item19",
  "item20",
];
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(dummy_items);
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setItems(dummy_items);
  }, [items]);


  const trails = useTrail(items.length, {
    from: { opacity: toggle ? 0.75 : 1, fill: toggle ? "pink" : "#4d4d4d" },
    to: { opacity: toggle ? 1 : 1, fill: toggle ? "red" : "#4d4d4d" },

    config: {
      mass: 10,
      friction: 14,
      tension: 120,
      velocity: 4,
    },
    loop: true,
    cancel: !toggle,
    // reverse : true,
  });

  const trails2 = useTrail(items.length, {
    from: { opacity: toggle ? 0.75 : 1, fill: !toggle ? "#4d4d4d" : "#4d4d4d" },
    to: { opacity: toggle ? 1 : 1, fill: !toggle ? "red" : "#4d4d4d" },
    config: {
      mass: 10,
      friction: 14,
      tension: 120,
      velocity: 4,
    },
    loop: true,
    cancel: toggle,
  });

  const toggleClickHandler = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
  };

  const halfanimated = () => {
    const list = [];
    console.log("trails3.length= ", trails.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < trails.length; i++) {
      if (i < 10) {
        list.push(
          <Rect
            key={i}
            x={100 + 50 * i}
            y={300}
            width={100}
            height={50}
            fill="yellow"
            //opacity="1"
          />
        );
      } else {
        list.push(
          <animated.Rect
            key={i}
            x={100 + 50 * i}
            y={300}
            width={100}
            height={50}
            fill={toggle ? trails[i].fill : "black"}
            opacity={trails[i].opacity}
          />
        );
      }
    }
    return list;
  };

  return (
    <Stage
      width={window.innerWidth}
      height={window.innerHeight}
      // style={{ backgroundColor: "#fef7ef" }}
      style={{ backgroundColor: "#282c34" }}
    >
      <Layer>
        {trails.map(({ opacity, fill }, i) => (
          <animated.Rect
            key={i}
            x={100 + 50 * i}
            y={100}
            width={100}
            height={50}
            fill={toggle ? fill : "black"}
            opacity={opacity}
          />
        ))}
        {trails2.map(({ opacity, fill }, i) => (
          <animated.Rect
            key={i}
            x={100 + 50 * i}
            y={200}
            width={100}
            height={50}
            fill={!toggle ? fill : "black"}
            opacity={opacity}
          />
        ))}
        {halfanimated()}
        <Text
          x={200}
          y={400}
          fontSize={24}
          fill="red"
          text="Click here to Toggle"
          onClick={toggleClickHandler}
        ></Text>
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I hope my problems are small to solve:

1. In the First set how can I:

- make a continuous movement without the set turning completely red?
- prevent some Rects from being completely white?
- prevent some Reets blinking when the set is completely red?
- manage reverse. When true animation stops or is very slow

2. In the Second set:

- with a black background, the set shows the Rects in cyan instead of gray

3. In the Third set:

- to start animation from a certain index there is a specific function in useTrials or I have to use:

  - a conditional rendering (mixing Rect and animated.Rect)
  - a condition in prop fill only in the animated.Rect.

Thanks